# r programming list.files with for than one file format

Tags: r

I don't think it can be done, but still, does not hurt to ask:

For example can I see all the .csv and .rda files in the working dir with one command. i.e. can these two commands be combined

```
list.files(pattern=".rda")
list.files(pattern=".csv")
```

Is this the best way:

```
a = list.files(pattern=".rda")
b = list.files(pattern=".csv")
print(c(a,b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?list.files`

> pattern
>   an optional regular expression. Only file names which match the regular 
>   expression will be returned.

You may use regex.

```
list.files(pattern="\\.(rda|csv)")
```

use end of the line anchor if necessary.

```
list.files(pattern="\\.(rda|csv)$")
```